Error in Talend Studio: Command org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand was called in the wrong state
I am currently using a Remote TAC connection to access my Talend Studio, and I encounter the following error when I open the Studio with this connection:
Command org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand was called in the wrong state
As I am fairly new to Talend, I would greatly appreciate any assistance in understanding whether this issue is related to the TAC connection. Should I configure settings in TAC or adjust the Git settings in Talend Studio to resolve this?
Additionally, I am unable to see uncommitted changes in staging.
Please find attached screenshots for referenceenter image description here
I tried Configuring the Git Setings but no help

Hi, I solved this issue:

I solved this issue by the  following (in short): Had different GitHub account credentials in Talend Studio -
Full Answer:
(path: Window -> Prefrences->Security Storage(General->Security->Security Storage)->[Default Security Storage] -> Git->Click on the Value appearing(Eg: https:/2f/2f.github.com)c-> Edit the ID Password /  Delete the ID password and Input the GitHub User Name and Access Token on where used by TAC or Same Repository used by other users.
